# Scattering in QM/NRQM vs QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering, spinors, interactions

As discussed in this question: [How does a wave packet get scattered?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109666/how-does-a-wave-packet-get-scattered) And shown in, for example, this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq4lGVznr_8

In quantum mechanics particles are scattered due to potentials.

In QFT, specifically QED, scattering occurs due to an interaction term in the QED Lagrangian.
Time evolution via the wave equation in the interaction picture gives the time evolution operator as $e$ to the power a time integral of the interaction Hamiltonian (the detail don't really matter here).
This can be interpreted as the process of destroying the old- and creating new particles in all sorts of ways so that the newly created particles can have different momenta and energy from that of the initial particles (provided conservation of momentum and energy).

I have difficulty with this for the following reason:

In QFT we could also quantise the spinor field from the Dirac equation for a Coulomb potential, giving rise to the bound states we now from RQM but now with creation and destruction operators creating and destroying these bound states.

This is just NRQM, and seems to me to provide a framework for describing the interactions in exactly the same way NRQM (and QM in the non-relativistic approximation for that matter) does.

For high energy states this is just waves looking like plane waves when they are far away from the region where the potential is relevant, getting distorted near the potential and heading off like plane waves afterwards. Superpositions of these states can give rise to the wave packets that scatter of the potential as described in the accepted answer to the above linked question.

Is this not an explanation of scattering that completely bypasses photons and interactions between the spinor and vector fields?

I'm just trying to get a sense of the bigger picture in particle physics and I'm not expecting a complete derivation of the interactions. I would just like to hear that this is either not problematic and that these ways of describing interactions are both used and can coexist or what I have misunderstood so I know where to look next.